# PowerShell or SQL Server truncating data

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I wrote a script that hits a web page, assigns the HTML to a variable, writes the variable value to the screen (just for my debugging purposes), then submits the data to a SQL stored procedure. The stored procedure variable is varchar(max). The database field is varchar(max). But for some reason, the HTML is truncated everytime. The output to the screen is not, so the problem appears to be with my stored procedure call.

```
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = 'server=localhost;integrated security=TRUE;database=datawarehouse'
$sqlConnection.Open()
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "insert_html"

$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@source", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"VarChar")
$sqlCommand.Parameters["@source"].Value = 'HTML'

$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@dataelement", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"VarChar")
$sqlCommand.Parameters["@dataelement"].Value = 'List'

$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@data", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"VarChar", -1)
$sqlCommand.Parameters["@data"].Value = $html

$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: How have you determined that the data is truncated?  If you are looking at the data in SSMS it can be deceiving when displaying data with line breaks.

Comment: In addition, by default SSMS will display only a maximum of 8000 characters

Comment: Bingo Kritner. It was the SSMS limitation. Thanks!